# Overriding a method with Generic Parameters in Java?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have an abstract Class **Monitor.java** which is subclassed by a Class **EmailMonitor.java**.

The method:

```
public abstract List<? extends MonitorAccount> performMonitor(List<? extends MonitorAccount> accounts)
```

is defined in **Monitor.java** and must be overridden in **EmailMonitor.java**.

I currently have the method overridden in **EmailMonitor.java** as follows:

```
@Override
public List<EmailAccount> performMonitor(List<EmailAccount> emailAccounts) {
    //...unrelated logic
    return emailAccounts;
}
```

However, this produces the compile time error:

`Name clash: The method performMonitor(List<EmailAccount>) of type EmailMonitor has the same erasure as performMonitor(Lis<? extends MonitorAccount> emailAccounts) of type Monitor but does not override it`

`EmailAccount` is a subclass of `MonitorAccount`, so (in my mind at least) overriding it in this way makes perfect sense. Seeing as the compiler is not happy with my logic though, How should I go about this correctly while still keeping my compile time checks to make sure that all calls to `EmailMonitor.performMonitor()` receive Lists of `EmailAccount` rather than some other type of `MonitorAccount`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

No, it's not overriding it properly. Overriding means you should be able to cope with any valid input to the base class. Consider what would happen if a client did this:

```
Monitor x = new EmailMonitor();
List<NonEmailAccount> nonEmailAccounts = ...;
x.performMonitor(nonEmailAccounts);
```

There's nothing in there which should give a compile-time error given your description - but it's clearly wrong.

It sounds to me like `Monitor` should be generic in the type of account it can monitor, so your `EmailMonitor` should extend `Monitor<EmailAccount>`. So:

```
public abstract class Monitor<T extends MonitorAccount>
{
    ...
    public abstract List<? extends T> performMonitor(
        List<? extends T> accounts);
}

public class EmailMonitor extends Monitor<EmailAccount>
{
    @Override
    public abstract List<? extends EmailAccount> performMonitor(
        List<? extends EmailAccount> accounts)
    {
        // Code goes here
    }
}
```

You might want to think carefully about the generics in the `performMonitor` call though - what's the return value meant to signify?

Comment: You say 'List<? extends EmailAccount>'. Now I can't pass EmailAccount through at all; Was that a typo?. 

I wanted to check that EmailMonitor always receives a list of EmailAccount and always returns a list of EmailAccount that can be used without dynamic casting.

posting my solution now :)

Answer (score 11):

Here is my own solution. I suspect this is the same thing Jon Skeet was trying to get at... without the typo (see my comment in reply to his answer).

the **Monitor.java** class:

```
public abstract class Monitor <T extends MonitorAccount> {
  ...
  public abstract List<T> performMonitor(List<T> accounts);
  ..
}
```

**EmailMonitor.java**

```
public class EmailMonitor extends Monitor<EmailAccount> {
  ...
  public List<EmailAccount> performMonitor(List<EmailAccount> emailAccounts) {
    ..//logic...logic...logic
    return emailAccounts;
  }
  ...
}
```

In this configuration, *EmailMonitor.performMonitor()* will always check at compile time that it receives a list of **EmailAccount** rather than any of my other types **FTPAccount, DBAccount,** etc... It's much cleaner than the alternative, which would have been receiving/sending a raw list and then having to coerce it the required type resulting in potential runtime type casting exceptions.

Comment: EmailMonitor does not extend MonitorAccount