# How to override method having Object parameter with a generic parameter?

Tags: java, generics, parameters, type-erasure

I want to override a method that has an parameter of type `Object`:

```
public void setValue(Object value) {
    // ...
}
```

and make that parameter to have a generic type `T`:

```
@Override
public void setValue(T value) {
    super.setValue(value);
}
```

How can I do this in Java?

In Eclipse I get these errors:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The type parameter T is hiding the type T
- Name clash: The method setValue(T) of type TextField<T> has the 
 same erasure as setValue(Object) of type JFormattedTextField but does not 
 override it
- The method setValue(T) of type TextField<T> must override or 
 implement a supertype method
```

Comment: This might be what you're looking for
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239645/overriding-a-method-with-generic-parameters-in-java

Comment: You can't make an overriding method accept a narrower type than the method it overrides, period.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't make an overriding method accept a narrower type than the method it overrides.

If you could, the following would be possible:

```
class A {
    public setValue(Object o) {…}
}

class B<T> extends A {
    @Override
    public setValue(T o) {…};
}

A a = new B<String>(); // this is valid
a.setValue(new Integer(123)); // this line would compile, but make no sense at runtime
```

Comment: But why wouldn't `a.setValue(new Integer(123));` work, since `Integer` inherit from `Object`?

Comment: @Jonas: Because the variable `a` holds an object of type `B<String>`, and the overriding method in `B` would get called. The type of the variable doesn't matter for method binding, the type of the object it stores does.

Answer (score -2):

Use:

```
<T extends Object> public void setValue(T o) {…};
```

Then there will be no problem with `a.setValue(new Integer(123));`. Just define as `A a = new B();` You can make this more narrow by replacing `Object` with the desired class.

Comment: This doesn't work: `Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "public", delete this token
 - The method setValue(T) of type TextField<T> must override or 
  implement a supertype method
 - Name clash: The method setValue(T) of type TextField<T> has the 
  same erasure as setValue(Object) of type JFormattedTextField but does not 
  override it`

Comment: Try `TextField<T extends Object>`

Comment: No, it doesn't work. And your method signature is wrong. It should return `void`.

Comment: As for me, using <T extends Object> instead of simple <Object> helped. +1